# Sharepoint 2013 Content Database Migration for upper build to lower build version

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, content-database, content-migration, migrate

Can I transfer Sharepoint Content Database of upper build farm to lower build farm ?

Can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do it. You can not go from higher version of sharepoint to lower version but other way works.
Now, either bring the 2nd farm at the same level or use 3rd party tool to migrate the site collection between farms.

Answer (score 1):

As above suggested, you can not go from higher to lower. I think, because there are database table update process, latest database may able to contain the early data, but not the early database to contain the latest data.

You may get help from third party migration tool to migrate content between SharePoint farms, here is a [list](http://www.topsharepoint.com/content-migration-tools-for-sharepoint).